# Elasticsearch index-patterns on template without wildcards

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a template as follows:

```
PUT _template/test
{
  "index_patterns": ["test_\\d{4}\\d{2}\\d{2}"],
  "settings":{
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "aliases": {
    "test_daily": {}
  }
}
```

But this op seems unsupported by ES.

The response is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "invalid_index_template_exception",
        "reason": "index_template [test] invalid, cause [Validation Failed: 1: template must not contain the following characters [ , \", *, \\, <, |, ,, >, /, ?];]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "invalid_index_template_exception",
    "reason": "index_template [test] invalid, cause [Validation Failed: 1: template must not contain the following characters [ , \", *, \\, <, |, ,, >, /, ?];]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I know that I can create an index_patterns with `"index_patterns":["test_*"]`

But I'm wondering if it's possible to add more specific regular expressions on template index_patterns field like is possible on `dynamic_template` for mappings.

Comment: No it's not, you can only use a wildcard character.

Comment: Thanks @Val I was searching it and found nothing, hoping there's something I missed.

Comment: How are you indexing your data?

Comment: Just testing the template patterns, right now I'm only doing `PUT test_20190303`.